# React: state updates only once on click

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to rotate an hour arrow on click on my clock and can't understand why does clicking happens only once. Could you please me suggest another way to do it, if possible

I need to animate this property by dynamically passing deg props into styled components like this.

```
transform: ${props => (props.deg && `rotate(${props.deg}deg)`)};
```

[image]

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Clock = styled.div`
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background:#fff url('https://res.cloudinary.com/nzmai/image/upload/v1602513284/be-verb-diagram/clock.png');
  background-size:cover;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 0 4px rgba(255,255,255,1);
  &::before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    background:#848484;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    z-index:10000;
    border-radius:50%;
  }
`;

const Hour = styled.div`
  position:absolute;
  width:160px;
  height:160px;
`;

const Hr = styled.div`
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:absolute;
  width:160px;
  height:160px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transform: ${props => (props.deg && `rotate(${props.deg}deg)`)};
  &:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:8px;
    height:80px;
    background:#848484;
    z-index:10;
    border-radius:6px 6px 0 0;
  }
`;

const Minute = styled.div`
  position:absolute;
  width:190px;
  height:190px;
`;

const Mn = styled.div`
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:absolute;
  width:190px;
  height:190px;
  &:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:4px;
    height:90px;
    background:#d6d6d6;
    z-index:11;
    border-radius:6px 6px 0 0;
  }
`;

function AnalogueClock() {
  const [hourArrowRotation, setHourArrowRotation] = useState(0);
  

  console.log(hourArrowRotation)

  return (
    <Clock>
      <Hour>
        <Hr id="hr" deg={ hourArrowRotation } onClick={ () => { 
          setHourArrowRotation(hourArrowRotation + 30)
        } }></Hr>
      </Hour>
      <Minute>
        <Mn></Mn>
      </Minute>
    </Clock>
  );
}

export default AnalogueClock;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the minute div is overlapping the hour div and since both are absolute the hour div will be rendered behind the minute div. That means if you click on Hr, which is inside Hour, the minute div will capture it even if you don't have an onClick function assigned to minute div.

One of the way to disable the click using `pointer-events:none` style for Minutes, here is an example

```
const Minute = styled.div`
  position:absolute;
  width:190px;
  height:190px;
  pointer-events:none 
`;
```

Comment: I have checked and it works thanks, however there is another issue, I can click outside the hour arrow in some areas and the hour arrow still moves, is it possible to make it movewhen I click exctly the hour arrow?

Comment: The minute arrow will also move by clicking, by the way.

Comment: So you need both needles to be clickable and movable and only the graphic should be clickable?

Comment: Both are clickable and movable

Comment: The needles are actualy just divs, no graphics there except for marks and digits. So I need clickable and movable these two divs. Thanks. Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Sure, here is a snack https://snack.expo.io/@saachitech/clickable-clock. You might need to adjust it a bit but should you get started

Comment: It works the I want, thank you very much, I need to look into pointer-events:none hack